# How to handle ArrayIndexedBoundexception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been trying to get a specific columns from a csv file say having 30 columns but i need only 3 columns entirely when i execute the following code only i get only one entire column data..how to get 3 column data at a time.when i run it prints only one column...when i try to print multiple column it shows error message like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>     at ReadCVS.main(ReadCVS.java:19)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String splitBy = ",";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt.csv"));
    String line = br.readLine();

    while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("new.csv",true));

        out.println(b[0]);

        out.close();
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: use b[0], b[1] and b[2] to get the first 3 columns?

Comment: tried it but shows error like this             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at ReadCVS.main(ReadCVS.java:19)

Comment: What is the error you get? also, please show us a sample of your txt.csv

Comment: Update in question please

Comment: Do you only have one row in your csv? You used `readLine()` twice

Comment: no i have aroung 5 rows n 5 columns

Comment: "1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"

Comment: i need to get 1 and 4th columns entire data...how can it be done ??

Comment: @AravindSelvaraj Sure, why not? But no one is going to give you a good answer until you know how to ask a question properly.

Comment: Consider converting string array `b` into a List of strings using `java.util.Arrays.asList(...)`, so you have an easier time printing each line for debugging purposes. Or use a debugger to figure out what you are getting in `b`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: @Gosu I have a something like 30 ppl data in my .csv file like Name Id Address Age etc  .Now i need only name and age columns of that 30 ppl. Am I Clear now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably is: 
You have only one line in your, txt.csv file.

When you called `br.readLine();` for the first time, that line is read from the file and stored in `String line` variable. But you ignored that line, and you've read again, in your while condition:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
```

So maybe you have an empty line or empty string after that first line. Then the while condition is true, but an empty String is stored in line variable. So the b[] has no element and b[0] is out of the bound.

One solution is to change this line:

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

to

```
String line = null;
```

**[EDIT]**

So if you try to read a file like the one in mkyong's site (as you linked in your comment) and split the lines by "," and write them in a new file for example, you can use a code like the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\new.csv",true));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\txt.csv"));
    String splitBy = ",";
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
        StringBuffer newLine = new StringBuffer();
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
        for (int i = 0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            if(b[i] == null || b[i].trim().isEmpty())
                continue;

            newLine.append(b[i].trim() + ";");
        }
        out.write(newLine.toString());
        out.newLine();
    }
    out.close();
    br.close();
}
```

Also you should know that the following line opens the output file in appendable way(the second boolean parameter in the constructor):

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\new.csv",true));
```

Also I assumed the contents of the source file is the same as in mkyong's site, somethimg like this:

```
"1.0.0.0",,  ,  ,"1.0.0.255","16777216",  , "16777471","AU" ,, "Australia"
"1.0.1.0" ,  ,, "1.0.3.255" ,,   ,"16777472","16778239" , ,  "CN"  ,   ,"China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"
```

Good Luck.

Comment: i tried it but even now i get output for only one column if i change my out.println(b[0]) to out.println(b[0],b[1]) i get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception :(

Comment: Ok, can you provide a sample file with the exact format for values of the "txt.csv" file?

Comment: My file looks like the csv file shown in this link                                                                                                      http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: even when i run the program from that link i get the same error Like ArrayIndexedOutOfBounds exceptions

Comment: And can I ask you how many line exactly exists in your file? I mean if you have a line of data, do you have any new lines or lines containing spaces only ofter that line?

Comment: I've downloaded that file file from the mkyong site. There is no problem reading from that file with the code you've provided. Also I doubt that the mkyong's code have such a serious problem. I think something is wrong with you input file. I will put a code which can read that file from mkyong's site, and write it into a new.csv file in the same path. See my new post here.

Comment: Thank you and actually my csv file contains spaces in between....I think that was my problem so how can i over come that??

Comment: See My edit again, by adding trim() calls on the string objects, we can omit commas and spaces from the source file. Because I didn't see you input file, I managed to add some spaces and commas to the the sample input file. Hope this snippet code help you.

Comment: Thank you ill try this one and if still i face any issues ill  show my csv.

Comment: Ok, hope it would be helpful. Usually when an answer help you with your problem you can accept it and vote it up as a helpful or the correct answer.

Comment: yea sure :) will do that